# get finger print using morpho device in https

Tags: javascript, java, asp.net, jsp

i want to capture finger print using morpho device. i am able to do that but the thing is, i am getting error because the service i am using is http and my website is https. so i have to allow every time my website to read http url.
what actually they are doing is, they are giving a service which allow me to access http://localhost:8080/CallMorphoAPI. but this is for http not https. i installed morpho driver which started this service. so what i want to know if there any way so i can modify this service. I want Finger print scan using morpho 1300 e2 using java api.

```js
function CallFingerAPI()
{
  var url = "http://localhost:8080/CallMorphoAPI";
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
       fpobject = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
           console.log(fpobject.Base64BMPIMage);

           // Call Servlet
           function uploadThumb(image){
      var formdata = image;         
      var  fr = new FormData();
      fr.append("data", formdata);
      var id = "<%=patientId%>";
      var url = "ThumbUpload?patientId="+id;
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                                 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
                     var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        response = response.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "");
                        response = response.trim();
                        if(response === "Uploaded"){
                           alert("Uploaded");
                        }
                        else{
                            alert("Error");
                            }
                            }

                            };
                            try{
                            xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
                            xmlhttp.send(fr);
                        }catch(e){alert("unable to connect to server");
                        }
           }
    uploadThumb(fpobject.Base64BMPIMage);
       template = fpobject.Base64ISOTemplate;       


     }
  }

  var timeout = 5;
  xmlhttp.open("POST",url+"?"+timeout,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Comment: where exactly comes the `JAVA` part in game?

Comment: still `JAVASCRIPT`

Comment: // Call Servlet
           function uploadThumb(image){
      var formdata = image;         
      var  fr = new FormData();
      fr.append("data", formdata);
      var id = "<%=patientId%>";
      var url = "ThumbUpload?patientId="+id;
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

Comment: also `JAVASCRIPT`

Comment: servlet code is not there because not required.

Comment: 1.) if `JAVA` is not required don't tag it. 2.) you don't actually say what exactly is required

Comment: the problem is not the servlet calling. the problem is var "http://localhost:8080/CallMorphoAPI" which is given by morpho testing tool. this is asp service which i want to access using https instead of http. i never worked on asp.

Comment: i am working on java web application that's why i tagged java.

Comment: if java knowledge is not needed to solve the problem, the tag is not in place at all, no matter what you are working on

Comment: if the problem can be solve by java i would appreciate. because asp is not my domain.

Comment: but thank you i will add this to my question.